# Constraint annotation to validate one field depending on another field

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I have this entity class in Symfony/5.4:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Assignments
{
    public const SALARY_RANGES = [
        'Red',
        'Green',
        null,
    ];

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Choice(choices=Assignments::SALARY_RANGES, strict=true)
     */
    private ?string $salaryRange;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Employee", inversedBy="assignments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="employee_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private ?Employee $employee;
}
```

I need to ensure that `salaryRange` has a non-null value if, and only if, `employee` is not null. Is it possible to enforce that with constraint annotations?

I've been playing with `@Assert\Callback` but I couldn't figure out how to get the value of the *other* field. Perhaps it's not even the right tool.

```
/**
 * @Assert\Callback({"ExampleValidator", "assertEmployeeOnlyCallback"})
 */
```

```
public static function assertEmployeeOnlyCallback(mixed $data, ExecutionContextInterface $context): void
{
    // `$data` contains value from `salaryRange` but, where is `employee`?
}
```

Comment: I think you are on the right track with [callbacks](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/reference/constraints/Callback.html#the-callback-method). Your argument order seems switched?  Making it static is probably not helping either.

Comment: @Cerad Docs say "You can also use the constraint with static methods. Since static methods don't have access to the object instance, they receive the object as the first argument". But the step debugger shows that `$data` is a string with the input value of the validated field. I'll check what happens with an instance method.

Comment: @Cerad I didn't test further, but I eventually found a subscriber that was overwriting some fields by mistake, and I suspect that explains why none of my attempts seemed to work reliably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just follow the documentation

https://symfony.com/doc/5.3/reference/constraints/Callback.html

```
class Author
{
    // ...
    private int $field = 1;
    private string $otherField;
   /**
    * @Assert\Callback
    */    
    public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context, mixed $payload): void
    {
        
        if ($this->field > 1 && $this->otherField != '') {
            $context->buildViolation('Your validation message')
                ->atPath('toherField')
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the difference with my code is that it's a method of the entity itself, rather than an ad-hoc validator class, so values are read from the entity rather than an array. I'll test it and see if available fields differ.

Comment: this validate method IS a method of the entity. you dont need static - so you have full access to the populated entity.

Comment: I tested this approach in my code. It's an entity-wide assertion, so it isn't linked to an specific field, and the entity instance is the model data with full input. It totally looks like the right solution when several fields are involved. (As about my attempts, I later discovered there's a custom Symfony form subscriber involved that was doing incorrect manipulations in certain scenarios; I suspect that explains why field data was sometimes missing.)

Answer (score -2):

You can use an [`Expression` constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/reference/constraints/Expression.html). If the expression is `true`, validation will pass. If the expression is `false`, there will be a violation.

It can be written in a single assertion, but you can write a couple of them in order to provide more accurate messages:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(length=255, nullable=true)
 * @Assert\Expression(
 *     "value !== null || this.getEmployee() === null",
 *     message="This value should not be null for employee assignments."
 * )
 * @Assert\Expression(
 *     "value === null || this.getEmployee() !== null",
 *     message="This field can only be set for employee assignments."
 * )
 * @Assert\Choice(choices=Assignments::SALARY_RANGES, strict=true)
 */
private ?string $salaryRange = null;
```

In my case, I also had to set a default value because I'm using a PHP typed property and it was accessed before being initialised.

This approach is as robust as using a property constraint (I presume it's just an different interface for the same underlying logic), the only drawback being that writing logic using Expression Language inside annotations is arguably harder to maintain and debug that writing pure PHP code.

The caveat mentioned in a comment about having no way to determine what order the fields are populated does not make too much sense because that is not how form validation works: reading request fields and applying validations happen in separate steps. There's no such warning in documentation either.

Comment: From what I can tell you seem to be using this as a property constraint.  If so then you really have no way of knowing for sure that the employee is being set before the range.  Fragile.  The example in the docs show a class constraint for a reason.

Comment: @Cerad "The example in the docs show a class constraint for a reason" - Perhaps they do, but they don't seen to explain what the reason is. My (probably limited) step debugging doesn't reveal any interleaving between reading request fields and applying validations, they're apparently separate steps.